# how to force textchanged to work onblur?

Tags: asp.net

actually i want to do tabbing in a Gridview rowwise i have done it.
Problem is that i have done by using onTextChange event now whenever i hav to do tabbing 
i have to text and then enter the tab,then only it works and my requirement is that tab should be done for without entering the text also
So as i'm having all the code i want to forcefully do this onBlur event. ??

Comment: Why not `onblur="whatever code you have in the onchange;"`??

Comment: Please show us a code example and expected behavior. Also, I understand English isn't your primary language, but it would be helpful if you could clarify a little better. Even try to write your question in your native language, and use [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#) to get it to English (just a suggestion, not an insult)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably write just a little javascript(using jQuery) so that when the onblur event occurs that the txtChanged event is called on the client side. Something like

```
$('#IdHere').blur(function() {
  $('#IdHere').change();
});
```