# how to force textchanged to work onblur?

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to force textchanged to work onblur ??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092217/how-to-force-textchanged-to-work-onblur)

Actually i want to do tabbing in a Gridview rowwise i have done it.
Problem is that i have done by using `onTextChange` event now whenever I have to tab away.
I have to text and then enter the tab, then only it works and my requirement is that tab should be done for without entering the text also
So as i'm having all the code i want to forcefully do this onBlur event.  ???

Comment: Please show us a code example and expected behavior. Also, I understand English isn't your primary language, but it would be helpful if you could clarify a little better. Even try to write your question in your native language, and use [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#) to get it to English (just a suggestion, not an insult)

Comment: DEFINITE duplicate of [how to force textchanged to work onblur ??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092217/how-to-force-textchanged-to-work-onblur)

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: "Possible"? Looks pretty definite to me!

Comment: Duplicating your question to get results is frowned upon in this community.

Comment: @adamjford - the system automatically enters that comment when we "Vote to Close".

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: Huh! Didn't know, sorry. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably write just a little javascript(using jQuery) so that when the onblur event occurs that the txtChanged event is called on the client side.
Something like

```
$('#IdHere').blur(function() {
  $('#IdHere').change();
});
```